# incompatibale Dart SDK version in flutter --version and when running a project

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

i'm a flutter starter and currntly adding firebase authentication to my project.

i added firebase_auth and and cloud_firestore to pubspec.yaml file using command lines
flutter pub add firebase_auth
flutter pub add cloud_firestore

dependenices are

"cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0

firebase_auth: ^1.1.3"

when trying to run my project i'm getting the error

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.2.beta.
> Because firebase_auth 1.1.3 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of firebase_auth match >1.1.3 <2.0.0, firebase_auth ^1.1.3 is forbidden.
> So, because elected_ones depends on firebase_auth ^1.1.3, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because elected_ones depends on firebase_auth ^1.1.3, version solving failed.)

in the error it says the Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.2.beta

but when i run flutter --version i get

Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (8 days ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Engine • revision 05e680e202
Tools • **Dart 2.12.3**

being trying to figure it out and i got totally lost between the '''dart pub upgrade''' and '''dart pub outdated''' through transitive dependecies

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by directing the IDE to correct folder where correct sdk sits

run in terminal (in project root)

flutter doctor -v

path will be shown in the first line